# Zabbix API behavior with no "id" specified -- no JSON in response

Tags: json-rpc, zabbix

I am writing JSON-RPC code to talk to the Zabbix API.

I have noticed that if I omit the `"id"` from the request, I get back a response with zero-length content.  If I specify any `"id"` value, the content is a JSON object as documented in the API documentation.

Can I assume that if I provide `"id"` that I will always get back JSON describing the error if an error occurs, but otherwise I will get back a zero-length content and a status of 200 to document the success?  I always want to know about errors, but for successful operations (like deleting something) it often will suffice to know that it succeeded.

Is this a general rule?  Is it documented anywhere?  If so, please tell me where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [JSON-RPC 2.0](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#response_object) documentation, "A Notification is a Request object without an "id" member." The documentation goes on to state: "Notifications are not confirmable by definition, since they do not have a Response object to be returned. As such, the Client would not be aware of any errors (like e.g. "Invalid params","Internal error")."

So, if you omit the "id" it will never return an error, because it is a notification. For use with Zabbix, you should probably just stick to using an id. That way you can get verification and error messages.

Comment: I was looking in the Zabbix API documentation, not in the JSON-RPC spec!  Thanks for this.